# Bootstrap 3 dropdown show in Chrome Inspector but not in browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Here's the website I'm working on: http://104.193.173.104/modx/

The top navigation has 2nd and 3rd levels that are generated by Wayfinder in ModX. As far as I can tell from the page source and chrome inspector, they are generating properly and have the appropriate CSS classes. When I click one of the nav links, the inspector shows the li class change to "dropdown open" and a ul class "dropdown-menu" appears. I can see the outline in inspector, but nothing is showing on the page.

I'm guessing this is a z-index problem in my CSS, but I'm not very familiar with how all of that works. Is anyone able to help me? Let me know what HTML/CSS you need me to include and I'll edit this post. Cheers!

note: My jQuery is called in the head of each page

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation div (`#main-navigation-container`) has `overflow:hidden`. You'll need to figure out what you want to do there but that's why it's being "cropped" out.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! For now, I have removed overflow:hidden; from my #main-navigation-container.
Now I'm running into the problem where I resize the window to mobile, and back to desktop, and it somehow applies overflow:hidden to the element.style. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: I found this in my CSS: 
`#main-navbar .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
#main-navbar .navbar-collapse.in {
 overflow: hidden;
} `

Changed that to visible but it is just for the transition; overflow:hidden still gets added after resizing to mobile and back. I also added `overflow:visible;` to my `#main-navigation-container` but it's still being changed. So frustrating!!!

Comment: Okay, I used a `!important` for the `overflow:visible;` in the `#main-navigation-container` and it's working! A bit of a hack fix, but it did the trick. I'm still open to suggestions if there's a more "industry standard" way of doing this. Thanks again for your help, Randy!